# zone-evergreen.js:2952 POST http://xxx/ net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)

Tags: angular, .net-core, ionic4, angular-httpclient

I am trying to send a large object from a dotnet core api endpoint to the browser to be loaded but I'm getting the error above. The request works on postman and returns a successful response with the body however fails on an angular/ionic app.

here's my post code in angular.

authentication.service.ts

```
authenticate(mobile: string, password: string): Observable<Account>{
    var CorrelationId = Guid.newGuid();

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': '*/*',
      'CorrelationId': CorrelationId,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }); 

    let postData = {"username": "0619601196",  "pwd": "test" }

   return this.httpClient.post<Account>('http://localhost:5000/authenticate', postData,
    {headers: headers, responseType: 'json'})
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

login-form.page.ts

```
login(){
    this.authentication.authenticate(this.mobileNumber, this.password).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('UserToken: ' + data.userToken);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[update] I have found a solution,

**cause**:  the response was being truncated while the client was not finished loading all the data hence that is why i was getting a status code 200 (ok) but with an error.

**solution**: Inside my dotnetcore api i added a header for content-length to the response to notify the client how much data to expect before closing the request

```
context.Response.ContentLength = (await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()).Length;
```